# VBScript Calling VBA Macro to build Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, pivot-table, qlikview

I am trying to do the following:

1. Using VBScript, export data from QlikView into Excel
2. Using VBScript, trigger Excel Macro
3. Have an Excel Macro that builds a Pivot Table based on the data loaded from Step 1

I have successfully exported the data (step 1) and triggered an Excel Macro (Step 2).

This macro should theoretically achieve Step 3 (if I run it manually from Excel, it completes successfully).

However, when the Macro that is triggered in Step 3 creates the Pivot Table, it then fails and in QlikView, the VBScript message is:

> Cannot run the macro 'procBuildPivot'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

This is definitely not the case as, if I trigger the macro directly in Excel, the pivot table is built.  Alternatively, if I call a macro from QlikView to do anything (up to and excluding building the pivot table) it works.

My VBScript:

```
Set objExcelApp = CREATEOBJECT("Excel.Application")

Set objExcelSheet = objExcelApp.Worksheets("Sheet 1")

objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open "Test.xlsm"

objExcelApp.Application.Run "procBuildPivotReport"

objExcelSheet.SaveAs "Test2.xlsm"

SET objExcelSheet = NOTHING
SET objExcelApp = NOTHING
```

My VBA:

```
Sub procBuildPivotReport()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws as ActiveSheet

Dim pvtCache as PivotCache
Dim pvt as PivotTable

Set pvtCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("QV Data").Range("A1:D10"), Version:=6)
Set pvt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache, TableDestination:=Range("J1"), TableName:= "Sales Analysis")

With pvt
    .PivotFields("Project ID").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Name").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Hours").Orientation = xlDataField
Emd With

End Sub
```

Independently, the VBA works (when called directly inside Excel) and the VBScript works to send data and call an Excel Macro

The issue appears to be when I try and combine the two and build a pivot table.

Comment: A guess, but [this](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm) may be helpful.

Comment: Try `objExcelApp.Application.Run "'" & excelPath & "'!procBuildPivotReport"`. If a Sub needs parameters, they can follow after the comma...  Replace `objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open "Test.xlsm"` with `objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open excelPath`.  `excelPath` is, of course the excel workbook full path... Do the same for `objExcelSheet.SaveAs "Test2.xlsm"`.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen for the reference, and @FaneDuru for the suggestion. Sadly neither did the trick.  The VBA macro to build the Pivot table definitely triggers all the way until after the `Set pvt.. ` call as after it fails, i can open the unsaved - but edited - file and see the frame of a pivot table.

Comment: You should use a `String` for the `SourceData` argument of `PivotCaches.Create`. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create): "When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly"

Comment: What's `PivotCache`? should be `pvtCache` too. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.

Comment: Try `objExcelSheet.Visible = True` (in the script code) in order to visually see what is happening... Doesn't Excel send any error?

Comment: @BigBen, sory typo regarding the PivotCache point. 
Oddly enough when I included the Option Explicit call, it stopped all VBA macros working (even when not involving PIvot Tables)

Comment: You should include `Option Explicit` - this forces you to declare *all* variables.

Comment: This was happening exactly because you did not declare ALL your variables. The main meaning of `Option Explicit` is exactly this: To force you declaring all variables. And this will help a lot after over-passing this step.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript:

You can't get a sheet before opening the workbook.
You need to capture the workbook object so you can later close it.
Add the workbook name to the `.Run` call to ensure you get where you want to go.
Close and quit before releasing the object handles.

```
workbookPath = "Test.xlsm"

Set objExcelApp = CREATEOBJECT("Excel.Application")
Set thisWorkBook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open workbookPath
Set objExcelSheet = thisWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet 1")

objExcelApp.Application.Run "'" & workbookPath & "'!procBuildPivotReport"

objExcelSheet.SaveAs "Test2.xlsm"

thisWorkBook.Close False
objExcelApp.Quit
Set objExcelSheet = Nothing
Set thisWorkBook = Nothing
Set objExcelApp = Nothing
```

VBA:

Set was missing "=". Use the pvtCache object you created in the pivot table. Add option explicit to catch typos.

```
Option Explicit
Sub procBuildPivotReport()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Dim pvtCache as PivotCache
    Set pvtCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("QV Data").Range("A1:D10"), Version:=6)
    Dim pvt as PivotTable
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables.Add(pvtCache, TableDestination:=Range("J1"), TableName:= "Sales Analysis")

    With pvt
        .PivotFields("Project ID").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Name").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("Hours").Orientation = xlDataField
    Emd With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well there's also issues in `procBuildPivotReport` - including the `PivotCache` in `Set pvt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache, TableDestination:=Range("J1"), TableName:= "Sales Analysis")` :-)

Comment: Maybe so but the OP said "Independently, the VBA works (when called directly inside Excel) "

Comment: Yeah - perhaps a typo in the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry Typo in the question.
@HackSlash, thank you for your suggestion.  I have logged off my machine with the code and I will try and implement your suggestion in the morning.